# Plotting survival times

Tags: r, data-visualization, survival, interval-censoring

I have been looking for ways to plot survival times as in the following graph
[image: Survival Times]

And having this data:

```
agestart agestop dead dead1 dead2 dead3 dead4

40.00    60.80   0    0     0     0     0
44.43    57.65   1    0     0     1     0
40.00    60.38   0    0     0     0     0
41.11    66.29   0    0     0     0     0 
47.06    65.97   1    0     1     0     0
```

But I'd like to plot them without colors, i.e. just indicating censoring with a cross, death1 with a circle, death2 with a square, death3 with a star, and so on. Is there any easy solution for this type of graphics in R? I have only found graphs that assume the same starting point in the study, for all participants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a slightly larger dataset than what you provided, but with the same properties, here is one possible solution using ggplot2.

First the data:

```
 ID agestart  agestop dead dead1 dead2 dead3 dead4
  1 40.31898 61.07525    0     0     0     0     0
  2 44.73464 70.82110    0     0     0     0     0
  3 38.69327 61.53224    1     0     0     1     0
  4 45.93688 61.47643    1     0     0     0     1
  5 43.10441 65.73701    0     0     0     0     0
  6 41.00229 59.95093    1     1     0     0     0
  7 42.93796 63.48322    1     0     1     0     0
  8 44.75329 59.98213    1     0     0     0     1
  9 49.28906 65.60382    0     0     0     0     0
 10 40.89990 61.11743    1     0     0     1     0
 11 40.42592 56.77811    1     1     0     0     0
 12 38.43149 59.91117    1     0     1     0     0
 13 44.80300 61.63504    0     0     0     0     0
 14 40.81832 63.97311    1     0     0     0     1
 15 43.36405 66.56718    0     0     0     0     0
 16 39.25923 60.56785    0     0     0     0     0
 17 43.07955 63.19032    1     0     0     1     0
 18 48.35370 66.20075    0     0     0     0     0
 19 41.00028 61.21209    1     0     0     0     1
 20 43.78243 63.84572    1     0     0     1     0
```

Next some code to create a string variable with your different death options (where dat is your original data frame):

```
dat$death<-rep(NA, length(dat[,1]))
dat$death[dat$dead==0]<-'Alive'
dat$death[dat$dead1==1]<-'Death1'
dat$death[dat$dead2==1]<-'Death2'
dat$death[dat$dead3==1]<-'Death3'
dat$death[dat$dead4==1]<-'Death4'
```

Then to work in ggplot2 - selecting out the relevant variables and reshaping the data from wide to long:

```
DF<-dat[,c(1,2,3,9)]#selects relevant columns in this particular data frame

library(reshape2)

DF.long<-reshape(DF, 
             v.names = 'age', 
             varying = c('agestart', 'agestop'), 
             timevar = 'Timepoint', 
             times = c('Start', 'Stop'), 
             direction = 'long')
```

And finally the code for ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
g1<-ggplot(aes(y=ID, x=age, group =ID), data=DF.long)
g2<-g1+geom_line()
g3<-g2+geom_point(aes(shape=death))
g4<-g3+ggtitle('Awesome Title Goes Here!')
g5<-g4+xlab('Age')
g6<-g5+ylab('Study ID')
g6
```

And since I like controlling the resolution of my output:

```
jpeg('Sample File.jpeg', res = 300, units='in', width = 6, height = 6)
g6
dev.off()
```

Which yields:
[image]

The shape of the points and their size can be adjusted according to your preference. You can also alter the line type and make other adjustments to the plot.